# Tkinter Text Autofill

Tags: python, tkinter, autocomplete, tk-toolkit

I am trying to make a simple and personal IDE for python using tkinter. I have seen it done before and have everything form syntax highlighting to a built in terminal but have the problem of no autofill. I know that you can have autofill in entry's with many methods out there but after searching for autofill with Text entries I couldn't find anything. If I could get some help that would be fantastic! I am looking for something similar to what is seen here.

Code of similar idea:

```
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteEntry
from tkinter import *

countries = [
        'Antigua and Barbuda', 'Bahamas','Barbados','Belize', 'Canada',
        'Costa Rica ', 'Cuba', 'Dominica', 'Dominican Republic', 'El Salvador ',
        'Grenada', 'Guatemala ', 'Haiti', 'Honduras ', 'Jamaica', 'Mexico',
        'Nicaragua', 'Saint Kitts and Nevis', 'Panama ', 'Saint Lucia', 
        'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', 'Trinidad and Tobago', 'United States of America'
        ]

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#f25252')

frame = Frame(ws, bg='#f25252')
frame.pack(expand=True)

Label(
    frame, 
    bg='#f25252',
    font = ('Times',21),
    text='Countries in North America '
    ).pack()

entry = AutocompleteEntry(
    frame, 
    width=30, 
    font=('Times', 18),
    completevalues=countries
    )
entry.pack()

ws.mainloop()
```

[Link](https://github.com/TkinterEP/ttkwidgets/blob/master/ttkwidgets/autocomplete/autocomplete_entry.py) to source code of AutocompleteEntry

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean by "autofill". That can mean different things to different people.

Comment: Intellisense. It provides suggestions (I.E. if I put in "pr" it will suggest adding "int" making the print() function)

Comment: Do you understand how to bind keys to function? It's not clear what part of the problem you need help with.

Comment: something similar to the autocomplete entry shown here with the added benefit of being possible in a textbox: https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-autocomplete/

Comment: Have you tried looking at the code for that `AutocompleteEntry` and applied it to a text widget?

Comment: I have been trying for the past hour but can't figure out quite how to do it. I'll add the link to the repository in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rudimentary autocomplete feature the basic algorithm is fairly simple:

- intercept key releases (which occur after tkinter automatically inserts the text that was typed)
- get the word before the cursor and call a callback to find possible matches
- add the first possible match, and select the part that was added so that future keypresses will replace it

You can also add a binding for the tab key that will see if there is autocomplete text that is visible, and move the cursor to the end.

This is a very hacked-together example to illustrate the principle, though it lacks any bulletproofing, optimizations, or handling of edge cases such as when backspacing, typing in the middle of a word, choosing alternate replacements, etc.

Just to be clear: this isn't the best way to implement autocomplete, it merely illustrates the concepts.

```
import tkinter as tk

class AutocompleteText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.callback = kwargs.pop("autocomplete", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # bind on key release, which will happen after tkinter
        # inserts the typed character
        self.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)

        # special handling for tab, which needs to happen on the
        # key _press_
        self.bind("<Tab>", self._handle_tab)

    def _handle_tab(self, event):
        # see if any text has the "autocomplete" tag
        tag_ranges= self.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            # move the insertion cursor to the end of
            # the selected text, and then remove the "sel"
            # and "autocomplete" tags
            self.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")

            # prevent the default behavior of inserting a literal tab
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.char and self.callback:
            # get word preceeding the insertion cursor
            word = self.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")

            # pass word to callback to get possible matches
            matches = self.callback(word)

            if matches:
                # autocomplete on the first match
                remainder = matches[0][len(word):]

                # remember the current insertion cursor
                insert = self.index("insert")

                # insert at the insertion cursor the remainder of
                # the matched word, and apply the tag "sel" so that
                # it is selected. Also, add the "autocomplete" text
                # which will make it easier to find later.
                self.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))

                # move the cursor back to the saved position
                self.mark_set("insert", insert)


def get_matches(word):
    # For illustrative purposes, pull possible matches from 
    # what has already been typed. You could just as easily 
    # return a list of pre-defined keywords.
    words = text.get("1.0", "end-1c").split()
    matches = [x for x in words if x.startswith(word)]
    return matches

root = tk.Tk()
text = AutocompleteText(root, autocomplete=get_matches)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I found a problem, it doesn't allow people to untype what they had before the pop-up came up and I was hoping to give a list of keywords and less of a AI that learns from previous inputs

Comment: @TRCK: I'm sure you'll find many problems. This isn't a complete solution, it's an illustration of the techniques. Creating a proper production-quality solution is up to you. You can replace the `get_matches` function with any function you want. The only requirement is that it returns a list of possible matches. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "popup" since this solution doesn't display a popup.

Comment: Hi @Bryan Oakley. I was looking at the code and am hoping to get a bit more help with this. I know it's a lot but could you help explain how I would be able to add customizations to the base widget (I.E. give a special font, turn off word wrap, etc). If you could help me understand that so I can work better with other custom widgets that would help me so much! One last request I have is some help with the backspacing. I am not super familiar with custom widgets and understanding this widget is very daunting making it hard to add this function on my own. If you could help that would be great!

Comment: Also, I figured out how to add my own list of keywords. Also, if this conversation is getting too long we might want to start a small email chain

Comment: Could you help me with backspacing?

Comment: @TRCK: that's a separate question. Stackoverflow comments aren't meant for long discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Today i tell you How you create Autocompeletion Entry box with Listbox without OOP.
If you not know about OOP that this Code may help you.

You can create autocompletion Entry box and Search box one code only one line Difference.

```
from tkinter import *
import re

root=Tk()


def fun1(event, *args, **kwargs):
      global data
      if (e.get()==''):
            lb.place_forget()            
            lb.delete(0, END)
       
      else:
            lb.delete(0, END)
            value=e.get()
            lb.place(x=0, y=20)

            for items in data:
                        if (re.search(value, items, re.IGNORECASE)):    
                                    lb.insert(END, items)
                                
        
            print(value)
            pass
        
        



def CurSelet(evt):

  

    valued=lb.get(ACTIVE)
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(END, valued)
    lb.place_forget() 

    print( valued)
        





def  down(ddd):
 
                  lb.focus()
                  lb.selection_set(0)

s=StringVar()


e=Entry(root,     textvariable=s)
e.grid(row=2, column=2)

s.trace('w', fun1)


e.bind('<Down>',     down)


for i in range(4,12):
      ee=Entry(root)
      ee.grid(row=i, column=2)



data=['Angular', 'action Script', 'Basic', 'GW-Basic' , 'C', 'C++', 'C#', 
'Django' ,'Dot-Net',  'Flask' , 'Go-Lang', 'Html', 'Python', 'PHP', 'Pearl', 
'Java', 'Javascript', 'Kotlin',  'Rust', 'R', 'S', 'Sr', 'Tekken 7', 'Tekken 
Tag' ]

lb=Listbox(root)
lb.place_forget()
lb.bind("<Button-3>", CurSelet)
lb.bind("<Right>",  CurSelet)


root.mainloop()

print(Listbox.curselection)
```

This is Search bar. If you Make AutoCompletion Use

```
if (re.match(value, items, re.IGNORECASE)):
```

in place of     if (re.search(value, items, re.IGNORECASE)):

only re.match and re.search Defferane between searchbar & autocompletion.

[image]